# Mongo random records on golang

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregate, sample, querying

I'm trying to retrieve random records from my `mongodb` collection.
I'm using `golang` with [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver)

```
pipeline := []bson.E{bson.E{"$sample", bson.E{"size", 10}}}
collection.Aggregate(context.TODO(), pipeline)
```

The aggregate is returning me this error:

```
A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.
```

I've tried with `$size` and `size`

Is it possible that `mongo-go-driver` doesn't support [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#pipe._S_sample)?

Comment: In situations like this, it's much easier to first produce a version that works in mongodb shell. Then you know that this is indeed possible and translating it to go is just busy work.

Comment: Also, I haven't used mongodb go driver myself, but from looking at documentation, it seems that you need to shove those bson.E into a bson.D. Or use `bson.A` instead of `[]bson.E`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below instead

```
pipeline := []bson.D{bson.D{{"$sample", bson.D{{"size", 10}}}}}
```

`bson.D` represents a BSON docoument and `bson.E` represents a BSON element.  An aggregation is an array of BSON documents.  More details can be found at https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson.